# How to create a background service in ionic 2 application?

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, ionic2

I want to create a background service that keeps sending device's location to the server even when the application is not running.

I tried the background-geolocation and background-mode plugins,but it didn't work as i want.

Can you help me please?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think ionic provides this kind of functionality.

Do enlighten me if there's a github library for that.

Your best bet would be native android , in which u may want to look at the following regarding to sticky service.

[Link Here Offical Docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle) Or [Link2 Github](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Starting-Background-Services)

PS: You might want to consider the reason of your application regards to background collection of user location data. It might be a infringement of privacy and might be a violation to privacy laws in some countries.